# Why isn't Deja Dup making room for more backups?

Tags: 10.04, backup, deja-dup

I've got Deja Dup (14.2) backing up to an external USB drive on Lucid.
Up until now, I've had "Keep Backups for" set to "Forever". However, after a couple of months of usage, the drive is now full.

I've tried setting the "Keep Backups for" setting to a shorter time period, even as low as one week, my assumption being that older backups would be cleared when the next backup runs.  However this doesn't seem to happen and I get an error message along the lines of "cannot copy temp file x to backup location y" and the backup stops.

How come space isn't being made for the new backup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like Déjà Dup keeps at least [two full backups](http://live.gnome.org/DejaDup/HowItWorks#Deleting_Old_Backups) before it will free up space by overwriting old ones. You mention you have been using it for a 'couple months'. I bet that means you are up against this limitation. Full backups can't be scheduled exactly, but it is going to be about once a month with scheduled backups happening weekly.

You can manually delete old full backups, they are all those ['duplicity-full*'](https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/178268) files on the backup drive. Make sure you have at least one full backup to recover from, obviously. You are taking a risk here that your remaining full backups are not corrupted, too.

Best practice before deleting anything is to use another drive to make a **tested, known good** backup to, then try deleting and/or resizing the backup partition on the destination drive.

Since you know you normally need 2 backups before Déjà Dup will make the third (and overwrite older ones), you need a destination of roughly 3x your current quantity of data being backed up.

If you are seeing different behavior or any bugs, you can [ask a question](https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+addquestion) or [report a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+filebug) on the project's Launchpad page (requires a Launchpad account)

Comment: That first link seems to explain the behaviour I was seeing.  Old incremental chains have been removed but not the older full backups (presumably because I said to keep them forever).  I'll manually delete the older ones and set the "keep backups for" setting lower, hopefully that should work!

Comment: @marxjohnson Cool, just make sure you test the full backup you plan to keep before deleting anything. Really important, even though it's probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that only backups made after the setting was changed would be affected. At least, I wouldn't want it to automatically delete existing backups. It would probably be nice to have a dialog asking you what to do. You should file a bug, I think. Do so on Launchpad.net.